# word for hesitation, "well" or "actually"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-choice, word-request

> "Aren't you going home?"
>
> "**Well,** can I stay a little longer?" / "**Actually,** can I say a little longer?"

Both "Well" and "Actually" work here? Do they have the same meaning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word '**well**', would be used more if you were to **show hesitation**. When you say '**actually**', you'd give the impression that you're **confronting or casual**, i.e *let's say you are trying to get out going out to the pub...*

> You would say "**Well**, I can't come to the pub tonight, maybe next week?" *instead of alternating to* "**Actually**, I can't come to the pub tonight..." etc.

It seems more hesitant to say well, as you would say it a lot slower than you read it too, whereas actually is said quite fast during conversation and would seem more casual. Nonetheless, you should use 'well' if your aiming to show hesitation.